# How I can acess GRUB menu of ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: grub2, password-recovery

My GRUB menu vanished, and I cannot access it with left <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>. When I press the left <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> I see `opening GRUB` and then the **desktop menu**.
I need it urgently because I lost my password.

Answer (score 0):

Boot to an Ubuntu live cd and use boot-repair to unhide the GRUB menu.

In a terminal, type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install boot-repair && gksudo boot-repair
```

Once boot-repair opens, click Advanced Options. Make sure that "Unhide Boot Menu" is checked and run the repairs, following any instructions you are given.

You have to do this from a live USB because you lost your password.

Answer (score 0):

When you see on the screen `Opening GRUB...` press the <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> key several times. Not seconds before that, only when that is displayed (or maybe just a second before).

If you are not still able to enter, please make sure that you are using Grub2. Earlier versions of grub (0.9x) are issued with the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key instead.